# BarChart vAxis to the right it is possible?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have difficulties getting the vaxis on the right. I've tried other examples but they don't work with the bar chart.
The example I have is this and I would like to have the vaxis on the right side. it's possible?

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var datatable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  datatable.addColumn('string', 'Type');
  datatable.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
  datatable.addRows([
    ['A', 2],
    ['B', 4],
    ['C', 6],
    ['S', 4],
    ['U', 2]
  ]);

  var dataview = new google.visualization.DataView(datatable);
  dataview.setRows([0, 2, 3, 4, 1]);

  var options = {
   legend: 'none',
    hAxis:{direction: -1}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(dataview, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there aren't any options that will move the y-axis to the right for the bar chart.

however, we can manually move the labels (`<text>` elements) on the chart's `'ready'` event,
by changing their `'x'` attribute

and we can use the following chart methods,
to calculate the placement.

> `getChartLayoutInterface()` - Returns an object containing information about the onscreen placement of the chart and its elements.
>
> `getChartAreaBoundingBox()` - Returns an object containing the left, top, width, and height of the chart content

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var datatable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  datatable.addColumn('string', 'Type');
  datatable.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
  datatable.addRows([
    ['A', 2],
    ['B', 4],
    ['C', 6],
    ['S', 4],
    ['U', 2]
  ]);

  var dataview = new google.visualization.DataView(datatable);
  dataview.setRows([0, 2, 3, 4, 1]);

  var options = {
   legend: 'none',
    hAxis:{direction: -1}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var chartBounds = chartLayout.getChartAreaBoundingBox();
    var labels = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('text');
    var fontSize;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
      fontSize = parseFloat(label.getAttribute('font-size'));
      if (label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'end') {
        label.setAttribute('x', chartBounds.left + chartBounds.width + (fontSize * 2));
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(dataview, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, i hope so, this is an example, i will try to apply it in my case.